# Getting list of events from an array

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to print out a list of events in one day selected on a calendar made using FSCalendar. So far I have written this in my app:

```
while counter2 < noOfEvents{
                    print("counter[counter2]: ", counter[counter2])
                    cell.eventName.text = eventsArray[counter[counter2]].nameOfEvent
                    cell.eventDescription.text = eventsArray[counter[counter2]].descriptionEvent
                    cell.countryName.text = eventsArray[counter[counter2]].country
                    cell.eventDate.text = eventsArray[counter[counter2]].dateEvent
                    cell.eventTime.text = eventsArray[counter[counter2]].timeEvent

                    print("eventsArray[counter[counter2]].nameOfEvent: ", eventsArray[counter[counter2]].nameOfEvent)

                    counter2 += 1
                }
```

My question is how to make the list display both events and not just the latest one. In the logs both are clearly there but in the actual list on the app only the latest one is displayed. Any helpp is appreciated

Comment: You’re using the same cell to store both events. Assuming you're using a UITableView to display this detailed list, you should implement the dequeueReusableCell function (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell).

Comment: Unless this is incorrect I've implemented cells with this: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CalendarCell2", for: indexPath)as! CalendarCell2

Comment: Rather than loop through your events, you should use the UITableViewDataSource function `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` to set the number of events, then set the cell at the indexPath in `dequeueReusableCell`, e.g. `let event = eventsArray[indexPath.row]` then set the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

// Set the number of sections in the table view (assumes 1 if simple list of events)
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// Set the number of events
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return eventsArray.count
}


// Provide each cell when requested
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CalendarCell2", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCell2

    // Configure the cell...
    if let event = eventsArray[indexPath.row] {
        // Set the appropriate elements in the cell
    }
    return cell
}
```

Note that if the number of events changes you'll want to update the table view by the `reloadData()` function.